# Getting the properties of a dropdownlist using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

How can I query the features of a dropdownlist?
In the following example, I can query the products with Jsoup, but I can not list the prices

```html
<option value = "0"> Please select ... </ option>
<option value ='1870' id ='10,000 $' style ='color:#333;'> First product </ option>
<option value ='1871' id ='3,000 $' style ='color:#333;'> second product </ option>
<option value ='1872' id ='20,000 $' style ='color:#333;'> Third product </ option>
<option value ='1873' id ='30,000 $' style ='color:#333;'> fourth product </ option>
```

How can I display prices?

[Show products without prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDQCL.jpg)

https://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your approach failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the elements that contain `option` tags and then iterate over them - if the element has the `id` attribute, display the text (which is "Fisrt product" and so on) and the `id`'s attribute value, which is the price.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);      
Elements options = doc.select("option");
for (Element option : options) {
    if (option.hasAttr("id")) {
        System.out.println(option.text() + " price: " + option.id());
    }
}
```